# Unable to start computer with docking station button while connected to a docking station and laptop lid is closed, but when open, works fine

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, power-management, docking-station

Basically I am placing a laptop (ThinkPad L530 running Win 7 32bit OS) on a docking station within a cart and placing the laptop inside the cart and closing the lid, then connecting an external monitor to the cart w/ keyboard and mouse outside of the cart.

There are buttons outside of the cart that power the cart and turn the laptop on/off.

The issue I am having is I have to close the laptop to fit it inside of the cart, and when I close the lid the laptop on/off button outside of the cart does not register. When the laptop is open, the button works just fine.

I am assuming there is some sort of power setting that would assist with this issue and was wondering if anyone had any ideas?

Comment: Going to try leaving the lid partially open and see if that is possible with the cart, might be the only solution because after troubleshooting all morning it could possibly be an issue with the cart dock itself.

Comment: I know this is an old question but it would be nice to know what sort of docking station was used and also how the system was switched on when the battery ran out.

Answer (score 0):

#### Change what happens when you close your laptop

> When you close your laptop lid, Windows can shut down, do nothing, or enter a power-saving state, such as sleep or hibernation. You can apply the same setting to all of your power plans or you can apply different settings to individual plans.

...

> **To apply a setting to a specific plan**
>
> 1. Open Power Options by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security,
>      and then clicking Power Options.
> 2. On the Select a power plan page, click Change plan settings for the plan that you want to change.
> 3. On the Change settings for the plan page, click Change advanced power settings.
> 4. On the Advanced settings tab, expand Power buttons and lid, expand Lid close action, choose what you want your laptop to do when you
>      close the lid, both for when it's running on battery and when it's
>      plugged in, and then click OK.

[image]

Sourcec [Change what happens when you close your laptop](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-what-happens-when-you-close-your-laptop)

Comment: Are you sure the power on button of the laptop is affected by these settings when it is shut down?

Comment: Leave it powered on when you close the lid and see what happens? I don't have a cart to test it with. You might also want to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/852817/edit) your question and add the make/model of your laptop...

Comment: I have tried changing the lid close action to do nothing under the power options settings, still is not registering with the docking device in the cart when the laptop is closed.

Comment: The power button on the outside of the cart works just fine when the laptop is already on and the lid is closed, it is just getting the laptop to turn back on once the laptop has been shut down that is the issue.

Comment: Are you able to leave the lid a fraction open (put a small wedge in it)?

Comment: Leaving it powered on when I close the lid works just fine, however  the issue is that once the cart is deployed, the user is going to eventually shut down the laptop, and won't be able to get inside the cart to turn the laptop back on manually.

Comment: The only way for the laptop and all of the hubs/power adapters inside the cart to fit is for the adapter and some cables to be tightly packed into the cart, which doesn't leave much room for the laptop to be open.

Comment: It may only need a cm or so ...